# if $x_{n+1}=ax_{n}+b$ then How find this $a,b,c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question:**

> Let there be a sequence $x_{n}$ such that $$x_{n+1}=ax_{n}+b,,x_{1}=c$$
>   where $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers.

Suppose, too, that for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ we have that 
$$
\text{(*)   } ~~~n\mid m\implies x_{n}|x_{m}
$$

> show that:$$b=c$$

My try: if $a=1$, then we have
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=b,x_{1}=c\Longrightarrow x_{n}=c+(n-1)b=bn+c-b$$
So  if
$n|m$ then let $m=nk$, so
$$\dfrac{x_{m}}{x_{n}}=\dfrac{bkn+c-b}{bn+c-b}=k+\dfrac{c-b-kc+kb}{bn+c-b}\in N^{+}$$
So how do I find $a,b$ and $c$?

Case $2$: if $a\neq1$, then we have
$$x_{n}+\dfrac{b}{a-1}=a(x_{n}+\dfrac{b}{a-1})$$
So
$$x_{n}=\left(c+\dfrac{b}{a-1}\right)a^{n-1}-\dfrac{b}{a-1}$$

**By the way:**

Sometime ago, I solved the following hard problem: (IMO shorsits)

If $a,b\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, and for any positive integer $n$ we have
$$\dfrac{a^n-1}{b^n-1}\in N^{+}$$

Then we also must have that there exists some positive integer $k$ so that $a=b^k$

Then I can't, thank you

This problem was created by a China IMO team student.

Comment: Please ask your questions in different posts, so things don't get messed up.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to restate the problem, and give a partial answer:

Find all positive-integer triples $a, b, c$ such that the arithmetic sequence
$$
x_n = a x_n + b; x_1 = c
$$
has the property that $n | m \implies x_n | x_m$.

Suppose that the sequence has this property. Then consider the case $n = 1$, which divides any other number $m$; we get that $x_1 | x_m$ for every $m$. In particular, the number $c = x_1$ must divide $x_2 = ac + b$; that means that 
$$
c | b.
$$
What about $x_3$? That's
$$
x_3 = a(ac + b) + b = a^2 c + ab + b
$$
which is also divisible by $c$ (since $ac$ and $b$ both are). A simple induction argument shows that $c | x_n$ for every $n$ once we know that $c | b$.

The stuff above is a cleaner version of what I wrote earlier. But $c | b$, although necessary, is not a sufficient condition. Let's examine further. We have
$$
x_4 = a^3 c + a^2 b + ab + b = a^2(ac + b) + (a+1)b
$$
which must be divisible by $x_2 = ac + b$. Thus we must have $(ac + b) | (a+1) b$. Writeing $b = sc$, we get $(ac + sc) | (a+1) sc$, so $(a + s) | (a+1)s$, so $(a + s) | (as + s)$.

So just using the first few terms, we find that

(1) $c | b$. Writing $b = cs$, we also have

(2) $(a+s) | (as + s)$

So those are a couple of constraints on $a, b, c$.

Comment: sorry,My problem if $n.m$ such $n|m$,

Comment: I don't think I understand; when you pick $n = 1$, then any $m$ will work, since $1$ divides all integers. (I.e., I'm choosing $n = 1$, $m = k = k \cdot 1 = k \cdot n$.)

Comment: I have edit this reslut.

Answer (score -1):

The current form (7/16/2014, 2PM EDT) of the problem says that if 
$$
x_{n+1} = a x_{n} + b; x_0 = 0;  x_1 = c,
$$
and the following divisibility property holds:
$$
n | m \implies x_n | x_m,
$$
then we are to show that $b = c$.

This is trivial; you plug in $n = 0$ to the recurrence to get
$$
x_{1} = a x_{0} + b; x_0 = 0;  x_1 = c,
$$
Replacing $x_0$ with $c$, this becomes $x_1 = b$; since $x_1$ is also $c$, we have $c = b$.

I suggest you think through the statement of your problem very carefully and try rewriting; I'm sure you're trying to ask something more interesting than this.

Comment: The problem asks for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ which excludes $n=0$.

Comment: The $Z^{+}$ restriction is for the divisibility property, which I never used. There's no such restriction given on the recurrence index.

Comment: I feel like it's implied, since he takes $x_1$ as the initial condition.

Comment: Evidently s/he does as well, since s/he's placed a bonus on the problem, and hence thinks it remains unsolved. But you can see why I suggested a careful rewrite.

Comment: Oh, no doubt on that part. The less guessing required on our part as readers, the better...